# How to merge multiple CSV files into a DataFrame when a common column overlaps in some files, but not others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, tkinter

My goal is to combine three CSV files into a DataFrame. The files are:

'Gender':

[image]

'Jobs':

[image]

'Names'

[image]

The 'Gender' file shares the 'First name' column with the 'Names' file. The 'Jobs' file shares the 'Last name' column with the 'Names' file but it doesn't share any with the 'Gender' file.

I wrote the code below, which creates a simple GUI.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

class GUI:
    
    #create an initialisation method
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = root
        
        #create an empty list for the three files
        file_list = []
        
        #allow the user to select files
        def select_files(self):
            self.file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

            return self.file_path
        
        #add the files to the file_list
        def add_files_to_list(self):
            select_files(self)
            self.file_name = os.path.basename(self.file_path)
            file_list.append(self.file_name)
        
            return file_list
        
        #read the CSV files using pandas and combine them  
        def convert_files(self):
            try:
                filez = add_files_to_list(self)
    
                df1 = pd.read_csv(filez[0], error_bad_lines=False, dtype='unicode')
                df2 = pd.read_csv(filez[1], error_bad_lines=False, dtype='unicode')
                df3 = pd.read_csv(filez[2], error_bad_lines=False, dtype='unicode')

                self.result = df1.merge(df2.merge(df3))
                
                df_label = Label(master, text=(self.result), font=15, highlightthickness=0, bd=5, justify='center') 
                df_label.pack(fill='both', pady=10, padx=10)
            
            #ignore the error shown when self.result tries to merge the DataFrame but cannot because not all 3 files were
            #added
            except IndexError:
                pass
        
        #create a button to allow the user to select files
        convert_files_button = Button(self.master, text='Convert files...', font=(15), highlightthickness=4, fg='black')
        convert_files_button.pack(fill='x')
        convert_files_button.bind('<Button-1>', convert_files)        

root = Tk()
window = GUI(root)
root.title('Data Merger')
root.geometry('800x600')
root.state('zoomed')
root.mainloop()
```

When the user clicks on the 'Convert files' button a DataFrame is created. However, it only works if the files are added in the correct order, i.e. the files to be merged share a common column. When files are not added in the correct order, I get the merge error:

[image]

I would be most grateful if someone could hint at a more elegant or error proof way of achieving my goal. Also, any hints on how to justify the DataFrame content when placed in a label widget would be great.

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Please post the expected output.

Comment: Can you share data instead of images? `df.head().to_dict()` then copy the output in SO

Comment: Hi Mayank. I have updated the question to include the expected output. I am trying to figure out how to make it look like a proper table at the moment.

Comment: You want to use pd.concat(list_of_dataframes) instead of pd.merge, which is a join operation.

Comment: Don't make the data look like a proper table. Make it look like a proper dataframe initializer so that we can use it. And take out the tkinter stuff... it is not relevant to the problem. Reading and merging csvs can be done in a short script.

Comment: seems simple enough, you just need to join your facts to your dimensions, your dimension table here is your names dataframe, first join jobs on last name and gender on first name, note you may get incorrect results or even a product of your dataframe if you have duplication. I would suggest going back to source and creating unique keys to join with.

Comment: `self.result = df1.merge(df2.merge(df3, left_on='Names', right_on='Last Name'))` where df3 is `job` table